# on linux gitclone issue remote server error showing fatal error with proxy n port

Tags: git, http, proxy, port, remote-access

└─$ git clone https://github.com/achillean/shodan-python.git
Cloning into 'shodan-python'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/achillean/shodan-python.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
problem looks like it i tried alot of process but won*t anything work.

nothing working error after error Step 1: Check for Proxy Settings in Git

Git might be configured to use a proxy for all connections. You can check if Git is configured to use a proxy by running:

git config --global --get http.proxy
git config --global --get https.proxy

If these commands return a proxy address, that's likely the cause of the issue.
Step 2: Unset Proxy Settings in Git

If Git is configured to use a proxy, you can unset these settings by running:

git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy

This will remove the proxy settings from Git's global configuration.
Step 3: Check for Proxy Settings in Your Environment

Your system might be configured to use a proxy for all connections, not just Git. You can check if your system is configured to use a proxy by looking at the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables:

echo $http_proxy
echo $https_proxy

If these variables are set, they might be causing the issue.
Step 4: Unset Proxy Settings in Your Environment

If your system is configured to use a proxy, you can unset these environment variables by running:

unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy

This will remove the proxy settings from your environment variables.
Step 5: Try Cloning the Repository Again

After unsetting the proxy settings in both Git and your environment, try cloning the repository again:

git clone https://github.com/owasp-amass/amass.git

Step 6: Check for Local Proxy Services

If you have any local proxy services running (for example, a VPN or a proxy server running on your machine), they might be listening on port 8080 and interfering with your connection. You can check for running services on port 8080 with:

sudo lsof -i :8080

If you find any services running on this port, consider stopping them or configuring them to not interfere with your connection to GitHub.
Step 7: Use SSH Instead of HTTPS

If you're still having trouble, you can try cloning the repository using SSH instead of HTTPS. First, ensure you have SSH keys set up with GitHub. Then, use the SSH URL to clone the repository:

git clone git@github.com:owasp-amass/amass.git

This method might bypass any proxy or firewall issues you're encountering with HTTPS.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue and successfully clone the repository. If you continue to experience problems, there might be a more specific issue with your network configuration or with GitHub's availability.
User
the process wouldnot work
Phind

If the steps provided to resolve the issue with cloning the repository have not worked, it's possible that there's a more specific issue at play. Let's explore a few additional troubleshooting steps and considerations:

1. Verify Network Connectivity

First, ensure that your internet connection is stable and that you can access other websites. Try opening a web page in your browser to confirm that your internet connection is working.
2. Check for Firewall or Antivirus Interference

Sometimes, firewall or antivirus software can interfere with network connections. Temporarily disable your firewall or antivirus software and try cloning the repository again. If this resolves the issue, you'll need to adjust the settings of your firewall or antivirus software to allow Git to connect to GitHub.
3. Use a Different Network

If possible, try connecting to a different network. Some networks might have restrictions or configurations that prevent connections to certain ports or addresses.
4. Check GitHub's Status

Visit GitHub's status page to check if there are any ongoing issues with GitHub's services. If GitHub is experiencing issues, you might need to wait until they are resolved.
5. Try Cloning a Different Repository

To determine if the issue is specific to the owasp-amass/amass repository or if it's a more general issue, try cloning a different repository. For example:

git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git

If you can clone other repositories without issue, the problem might be specific to the owasp-amass/amass repository or your access to it.
6. Contact GitHub Support

If you've tried all the above steps and are still unable to clone the repository, consider reaching out to GitHub support for assistance. There might be an issue on their end, or they might be able to provide more specific guidance based on your account and network settings.
7. Use SSH Instead of HTTPS

As a last resort, if you're still unable to clone the repository using HTTPS, you can try using SSH. This requires setting up SSH keys with GitHub, which you can do by following the instructions in the GitHub documentation. Once set up, you can clone the repository using the SSH URL:

git clone git@github.com:owasp-amass/amass.git

This method might bypass any proxy or firewall issues you're encountering with HTTPS.

If none of these steps resolve the issue, it might be helpful to provide more details about the specific error messages you're encountering and any additional steps you've taken to troubleshoot the issue. This information can help in diagnosing the problem more accurately.

fix it whatever the issue i cannot even shodan init i cannot run sublister3 nothing working on scanning or nmap fatal error and proxy port isssue